# How to reach Mapbox LocationManager delegate methods

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I hope someone has worked with Mapbox enough to understand the logic of this SDK.
My problem is that I cannot quite understand where do I find location delegate methods such as didUpdateLocations and didUpdateHeading. Previously they were directly accessible from `LocationManager`:

```
// These methods must remain to avoid breaking the API, but their implementation has been moved
// to `LocationProducer`. They should be fully removed in the next major version.
extension `LocationProducer`: LocationProviderDelegate {

    /// :nodoc:
    /// Deprecated. This method no longer has any effect.
    public func locationProvider(_ provider: LocationProvider, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {}

    /// :nodoc:
    /// Deprecated. This method no longer has any effect.
    public func locationProvider(_ provider: LocationProvider, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {}

    /// :nodoc:
    /// Deprecated. This method no longer has any effect.
    public func locationProvider(_ provider: LocationProvider, didFailWithError error: Error) {}

    /// :nodoc:
    /// Deprecated. This method no longer has any effect.
    public func locationProviderDidChangeAuthorization(_ provider: LocationProvider) {}
}
```

But as you can see now they are deprecated and no longer have any effect.

UPD: LocationProducer is a private property!

I suppose I should either override `LocationProducer` with the method that Mapbox kindly provided to us:

```
public func overrideLocationProvider(with customLocationProvider: LocationProvider) {
        locationProducer.locationProvider = customLocationProvider
    }
```

or implement my own delegate with the method

`func setDelegate(_ delegate: LocationProviderDelegate)`

To my shame have not yet tried any of those possible solutions in fear of missing a easier and less bulky one.
Please let me know if you know how to deal with that

Answer (score 0):

I just did
`mapView.location.locationProvider.setDelegate(self)` in my confirming class.

Worked like a charm.

Comment: Yes, this indeed works well, but anyway Mapbox delegate is far more restricted than native delegate (for CLLocationManager).
Also I had a strange bug when overriding Mapbox delegate with your own delegate via setDelegate function: map won't render the puck anymore. Override the whole LocationProvider if you face this issue.

Comment: OMG! I have exactly the same problem.  Thanks for the tip. :) I'll have to override then.

Comment: feel free to ask me if something doesn't go well!

Comment: Hi there! this is all still relatively causing my hair to fall out... I am trying to call a function when any update to the user's location is updated, but having no luck hooking into NavigationMapViewDelegate, for example. I can't find any examples that could simply help me to print a message to the console when location is updated... any help would be amazing, thanks in advance

Comment: @cyo Did you ever come right?  I stopped working on my Mapbox project until I have more knowledge of Swift in general as I've only been coding for 6 months in total.